# Wikidata SPARQL cannot give me birthdates for January 1

Tags: sparql, wikidata

All I'm doing is I want to use wikiservice sparql to get famous people by birthdate. Every other day in the year works, except January 1.  When I researched this, I found out it had something to do with time precision and the way wikidata stores dates.  If it sees January 1980 for example, it automatically returns January 1 1980.  If I query January 1 without precision I get back people who's birthdate are NOT January 1 (ie Joy Reid who was born Decemeber 8). If I add precision, I get nothing back.  Is it just literally impossible to get birth dates back for January 1 in wikidata sparql?

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?followers ?uniqueImage ?countryLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel; separator=", ") as ?occupations)
WHERE {
  VALUES ?country {wd:Q30 wd:Q145}
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
    wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
    wdt:P27 ?country ;  # Citizenship
    wdt:P8687 ?followers; # Social Media Followers 
    wdt:P106 ?occupation ;  # Occupation
    wdt:P18 ?uniqueImage .  # Image;

  FILTER(MONTH(?birthdate) = 1  && DAY(?birthdate) = 1)
  FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel) = "en")
  ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel .

  ?birthdate wikibase:timePrecision "12"^^xsd:integer .  #remove this to have results come back (though wrong like Joy Reid)

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?followers ?uniqueImage ?countryLabel
ORDER BY DESC(?followers)
LIMIT 40
```

You can run it here:
[SPARQL Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fbirthdate%20%3Ffollowers%20%3FuniqueImage%20%3FcountryLabel%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FoccupationLabel%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20as%20%3Foccupations%29%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7Bwd%3AQ30%20wd%3AQ145%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20%3B%20%20%23%20Instance%20of%20human%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fbirthdate%20%3B%20%20%23%20Date%20of%20birth%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP27%20%3Fcountry%20%3B%20%20%23%20Citizenship%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP8687%20%3Ffollowers%3B%20%23%20Social%20Media%20Followers%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Foccupation%20%3B%20%20%23%20Occupation%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP18%20%3FuniqueImage%20.%20%20%23%20Image%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28MONTH%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%3D%201%20%20%26%26%20DAY%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%3D%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3FoccupationLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Foccupation%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FoccupationLabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20wikibase%3AtimePrecision%20%2212%22%5E%5Exsd%3Ainteger%20.%20%20%23remove%20this%20to%20have%20results%20come%20back%20%28though%20wrong%20like%20Joy%20Reid%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fbirthdate%20%3Ffollowers%20%3FuniqueImage%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Ffollowers%29%0A%20%20%20%20LIMIT%2040%0A)

Comment: If It is just literally impossible, then I guess I will have to live with that, and manually research January 1 birthdates. Let me know guys if that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precision is an attribute of full values, not of simple values (by the way, literals cannot be subjects in RDF). See [RDF Dump Format](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Value_representation).

Instead of

```
?person wdt:P569 ?birthday .
?birthday wikibase:timePrecision 12 .
```

it should be something like

```
?person p:P569 ?statement .
?statement a wikibase:BestRank ;
           ps:P569 ?birthdate ;
           psv:P569/wikibase:timePrecision 11 .
```

See also [T57755](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T57755).

Comment: How unfortunate, I'm unable to tell if this works or not because I timeout every time I try.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't comment out the 10th line.

Comment: Yup, that's what it was, thanks, seems to work.  What's interesting is Wikidata's astronaut example sparql example didn't take into account precision and returns wrong birthdates for some of the astronauts, erroneously displaying some born January 1